# How to change time source from a LOCAL CMOS CLOCK to a Cisco router configured as a NTP master

Tags: cisco, domain-controller, ntp, time-synchronization, time-server

I have a test network that I'm using for my CCNA. I am using my Cisco 2811 router as an NTP master. I think I have it configured correctly.

Is there a Cisco command to see what NTP time source I am connected to?

When I run, w32TM  /querry /source from the domain controller which is setup as an NTP client, I get:

LOCAL CMOS CLOCK

How do I get the domain controller to pick up the time from the router that is the NTP master?

[Screen shot of the w32TM /query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjQDG.png) /source output is included.

Thank you.CMOS clock

[query source output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjQDG.png)

Comment: Hi @acenyc, welcome to ServerFault and thanks for the question.  Happy New Year!

Comment: what IOS ver do you have installed to your 2811?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the 2811 as an external time source for the DC?

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:192.168.0.10
net start w32time
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to make the domain controller the NTP master. All seems to be working now. In your example, what device is the IP address?
Thanks.

Comment: It's the source of time for the domain controller, usually a lower stratum NTP server. NTP only have a couple of "real" sources of time, so called Stratum 0 "servers". This is the GPS receiver or something along those lines that's attached to a Stratum 1 NTP server. A server syncing from that is then a Stratum 2 server. In a production environment, you'd preferrably have all you domain contollers syncing from a couple local Stratum 2 servers, which then pull time from a couple Stratum 1 servers.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My domain controller is configured as the master NTP server on my test network. The domain controller is syncing to a public NTP server. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, then you're all set! Could you consider accepting my answer to keep this question from popping up as unanswered? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I'd be happy to accept your answer. Where do I accept. I'm not seeing it. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers